# how to save collapsed panel state when page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, twitter-bootstrap-3

how to save collapsed panel state when page refresh ?

please see default state :

[image]

The `group header 2` is collapsed in the state below :

[image]

When the page is refreshed, changes are destroyed.how to save collapsed panel state when page refresh ?

my angularjs code :

```
angular
    .module('indexCtrl', [])
    .controller('indexCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        '$location',
        '$stateParams',
        '$state',
        '$rootScope',
        function ($scope, $location, $stateParams, $state, $rootScope) {
            $state.changeTitle($state.current.title);
            $scope.oneAtATime = false;

            $scope.groups = [
              {
                  title: 'Dynamic Group Header 1',
                  content: 'Dynamic Group Body 1',
                  isOpen:true
              },
              {
                  title: 'Dynamic Group Header 2',
                  content: 'Dynamic Group Body 2',
                  isOpen: true
              }
            ];
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: This is sort of a broad question and really depends what you're aiming for. Is there a server-side component to your code? Are you opposed to using local-storage or cookies? If your question is whether or not you can do this with AngularJS alone, the answer is no.

Comment: How do I use cookies for this?

Comment: @testStack Check out the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: Agreed w/the above, there are many possible approaches: put values in the URL (using ngRoute or UIRouter), use cookies, use local storage, save the state on the server, etc. Maybe you should pick one approach and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular local storage. Use the set method [angular local storage set](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage#set), to set the value for isopen. here `isOpen` is assigned true value by default, instead have a check in local storage and then assign. I am not aware of how you are changing the value for `isOpen`.

The strategy is keep a copy of the isOpen property's value in local storage whenever you are changing it, and have a check in the local storage for its last value whenever the page is refreshed.